# JavaScript Frontend Modularization without Globals

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, closures, frontend

Basically, what I want to do is have every `.js` file simply contain a closure and then import variables and functions from each.

lib.js:

```
(function(){

  myLibFunction(){ ... };

  ...

})();
```

main.js:

```
(function(){

  import("lib.js");

  console.log(myLibFunction());

})();
```

Comment: And the problem is....?

Comment: Isn't that what RequireJS is used for?

Comment: I'm not sure how that `import` function would work. A quick check on http://browserify.org/ makes it sound like it's built to work with node. What if I'm using node?

Comment: Use SystemJs (more flexible than RequireJs), or browserify.
None of these systems use "Import" to load librairies, the keyword is require() for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be a function returning an array of all the variables you want.

```
function importVars (){
    var myValues = [all,values,here];
    return values;
};
```

or you could return an object:

```
function importVars () {
    var myValues = {
        value1 : "property",
        value2 : "another property"
    };
    return myValues;
};
```

Import by doing `var MyValues = importVars()` and then acessing them by either writing `MyValues[which_one]` or `MyValues.value1`.
Hope this helps!